# DME replacement

Tags: general-aviation, avionics

I need help with this question:
I have an ancient DME in my airplane, a "KN 60C" and it turns on and the dial bounces and sits at 25 miles, so my guess it's time to swap it with a digital one.   Problem is money is tight and I'm hoping somebody can recommend a model of DME that would be the closest thing to a swap replacement.   I see allot of KN 64 and Narco brands on EBay and I need to know which one would work with my current antennas and such.  Of course the avionics shop would install it, but I can't seem to get their interest in doing this.  I just wan to walk in with a specific install request.   Someday I'll get a 430 GPS, but for now I'm happy with my dual glide slopes and ADF, I just need a working DME, please help

Comment: Hello and welcome to Aviation.SE! Hardware requirements aren't on topic for this site. These questions are normally either opinion based or should only be answered by a qualified person. You can see what is on topic in the [help].

Comment: Just buy a few spare KN60Cs and slide them in when the one you're using breaks.  A quick search shows a "working when removed" 60C costs about $200.  A kn64 will cost $1400 plus the cost to install the new tray and harness, so I'd guess at least $2000 to convert over to the more modern, but still obsolete, kn64.  It's too bad this is "off topic."